# PS3 homescreen either blank or flickering

Tags: ps3

I got a PS3 (2012 model, 250GB, Model ID: CECH-2008B) 2 weeks back, It didn't have a HDMI cable and so i bought one at a local store and connected it to a TV (whose specs are [here](https://www.mi.com/in/mi-led-smart-tv-4a-43/specs/)) and is enjoying some games.

I am observing that the PS3 home screen either goes disconnected (TV saying nothing is connected) or starts flickering sometimes.
This has happened i would say around 50% of the times and happens only at the following two occasions

- Booting up the PS3
- I have quit playing game and system goes to the home screen

And one more thing, I have played around 40 hours now and **not a single time this has happened while the game was on**., its only happens for the PS3 home screen.

Any idea on why this is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to do with the speed of the HDMI cable and the resolution of the home screen vs the resolution of the games.  Most games on PS3 run at 720p.  The home screen can run up to 1080p.  If your HDMI cable doesn't support fast enough bandwidth to sustain a 1080p connection, it would flicker or drop out at the home screen.  Try manually configuring your video settings on the PS3 and deselect 1080p as a valid format (1080i or 720p should work fine).  That should eliminate the flickering at the home screen without needing to buy a better HDMI cable.

Comment: Thank you @Blaelph , I will try this and will update if it worked

Comment: Hi @Blaelph, Seems like its working, I have not faced the issue after deselecting 1080p display format. I am accepting your answer. Thank you

Comment: @srk_cb, glad to help out.  In my experience, Playstation HDMI connections seem to very picky about throughput.  I've had HDMI cables that worked fine for 1080p connections on XBOX 360 and Nintendo Wii U, but experienced the same symptoms as you on PS3.  Not all HDMI cables are the same quality.